# ItemTouchHelper notifyItemMoved from to position not working

Tags: drag-and-drop, drag, android-recyclerview

Current,I am having a problem when execute drag and drop item in recyclerview.
I am doing with reference from https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo
But when execute function in adapter:

mListBookMark is ArrayList of Object

```
@Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    Collections.swap(mListBookMark, fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    return true;
}
```

When I drag item from position a to position b but when finish drag recycler view not data changed. 
How must I do?
Please give some suggestion for me! Thank you.

Comment: I have this problem too. For now I solve putting notifyDataSetChanged() before return true.

Answer (score 8):

Try adding `notifyItemChanged()` to your code, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    Collections.swap(mListBookMark, fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemChanged(fromPosition);
    notifyItemChanged(toPosition);
    return true;
}
```

This should update the views based on their new position.

Comment: This actually messes up the animation quite badly and somehow causes onItemMove to be called twice!